# Is there any command similar to objcopy which can remove symbol from shared objects files?

Tags: strip, objcopy

Is there any command similar to objcopy which can remove symbol from shared objects files on linux platform ?

Comment: Remove in the sense of "strip" (it can remove symbol names one by one, check it's man page) or actually yank the whole symbol, code included out of the library (the later can be accomplished by building static library first, pulling stuff out of it later with ar, then relinking it into a shared)?

Comment: Strip is not working on Linux so.  And I dont have option of removing it from .o or .a . The symbol is needed during linking of so. After that I want to remove or hide the symbol for so....?

Comment: Yes it is, what seems to be a problem?

Comment: Can strip remove symbols from so ? or it can only remove symbols from executables ?

Answer (score 0):

The [strip](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strip) utility has the following option, which may help:

```
-N --strip-symbol=<name>         Do not copy symbol <name>
```

Comment: So does `objcopy` itself ... literally the exact same option.